# Blackberry 6.0 vs 5.0 - Can't connect to https server on Torch, but can connect on bold using handheld proxy

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

I'm trying to connect to an https url (server is internal to my network) which has a self signed certificate.  I find that the BlackBerry Torch 9800 cannot connect even after the server is added to trusted hosts under the TLS proxy settings.  However, I can connnect using the bold 9700 when using TLS Handheld, a setting not found on the 9800.

Both devices are going through the same BES server.

9800 Simulator works fine.  And the problem can be reproduce on other users' Torch devices.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

The error on the Torch reads:

```
A communication failure has occurred. The Server may be busy, please try again later. If the problem persists contact your service provider.
```

-- mj

Comment: Is this in an app that you have developed?  Can the device access those resources using stock RIM software (e.g. the browser)?

Comment: No, the application was the Blackberry Browser.  The server which I was trying to contact was my own webserver with an unsigned certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazaa! Problem solved.  The Torch 9800 required a hostname and not an IP.  The Bold 9700 was fine with either.